# Codeigniter route not working with regex

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am trying to check if a url is in given format by using regular expression. this is my code.

myurl is : example.com/123456-watch-example_video_name

```
$route['([0-9]+)-[watch]-[A-Z0-9_+-]'] = 'mycontroller';
```

It is going to 404 page.
Where I am wrong, i am new to regular expression.

Comment: Try remove `[` character at `[watch]`, like this: `([0-9]+)-watch-[A-Z0-9_+-]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$route['([0-9]+)-watch-[A-Z0-9_+-]+'] = 'mycontroller';
```

`[watch]` matches one char of `watch`, so remove `[]`, and `[A-Z0-9_+-]` matches one char too, for one and more use `[A-Z0-9_+-]+`